# App Engine flexible deployment error "You have to set document_root in the runtime_config section in app.yaml"

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I just started receiving this error message when deploying with `gcloud app deploy`, resulting in a failed deployment.

My `yaml` file does have `runtime_config: document_root` defined, and I have successfully deployed countless times before.

This is the error message I'm seeing:

> Step #1: Digest: ...
>
> Step #1: Status: Downloaded newer image for
>   gcr.io/gcp-runtimes/php/gen-dockerfile@sha256:26c300e0afd68577f9bd3f2565bd690379ed797b74eed8517cc93e86f2c1be5a
>   Step #1: gcr.io/gcp-runtimes/php/gen-dockerfile@sha256:26c300e0afd68577f9bd3f2565bd690379ed797b74eed8517cc93e86f2c1be5a
>   Step #1: + php /builder/create_dockerfile.php create --php72-image
>   gcr.io/google-appengine/php72@sha256:6255560e92bfff2d4debc198156bdbeeefccf97b4f315c84c5e6bc03387dc6f7
>   --php71-image gcr.io/google-appengine/php71@sha256:ea560b34d5da1e51aca89373ee90e2c67637fd141914d582753927e9d05f5d11
>   --php70-image gcr.io/google-appengine/php70@sha256:84b209e24bf340e3afbadde366ddb6c20d6879fe513bf600fc5a440767363917
>   --php56-image gcr.io/google-appengine/php56@sha256:8cd9595ab8672c906c029d58276ec5547d34e2781e278f6af0715ca8ac15bab1
>
> Step #1:  Step #1: In GenFilesCommand.php line 297: Step #1:
>   Step #1:   You have to set document_root in the runtime_config section
>   in app.yaml.   Step #1:
>   Step #1:  Step #1: create [--php72-image PHP72-IMAGE] [--php71-image
>   PHP71-IMAGE] [--php70-image PHP70-IMAGE] [--php56-image PHP56-IMAGE]
>   [-w|--workspace WORKSPACE] Step #1:  Finished Step #1 ERROR ERROR:
>   build step 1
>   "gcr.io/gcp-runtimes/php/gen-dockerfile@..."
>
> ### failed: exit status 1
>
> Updating service [...] (this may take several minutes)...failed.
>
> ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9] Cloud build
>   ... status: FAILURE.
>
> Build error details: Build error details not available..

Contents of my **yaml** configuration:

```
runtime: php
runtime_config:
  document_root: wordpress
  nginx_conf_include: nginx-app.conf
env: flex
api_version: 1
service: SERVICE_ID
threadsafe: true
automatic_scaling:
  min_num_instances: 1
  max_num_instances: 10
resources:
  cpu: 4
  memory_gb: 12
  disk_size_gb: 10
beta_settings:
  cloud_sql_instances: REDACTED

handlers:
- url: /(.*\.(htm|html|css|js|scss|map))
  static_files: wordpress/\1
  upload: wordpress/.*\.(htm|html|css|js|scss|map)$
  application_readable: true
  secure: always

- url: /(.*\.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|woff|ttf|otf|eot|svg))
  static_files: wordpress/\1
  upload: wordpress/.*\.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|woff|ttf|otf|eot|svg)$
  application_readable: true
  secure: always

- url: /(.*\.php)
  script: wordpress/index.php
  secure: always

skip_files:
- ^.sass-cache
- ^.git
- ^.log
- .sass-cache/
- .git/
- ^vendor
- ^node_modules
- ^wonolog

env_variables:
  WHITELIST_FUNCTIONS: escapeshellarg,escapeshellcmd,exec,pclose,popen,shell_exec,phpversion,php_uname
```

Comment: Could you share the rest of the contents in the `app.yaml` file?

Comment: Yes, added the Yaml above

Comment: you may be on an old version of the Google Cloud SDK

Comment: I am running Google Cloud SDK 276.0.0. It is stating that is the latest when I go to update

Comment: Steps I tried: rolling back to configuration that last deployed successfully. SDK 275.0.0 and a previous GIT commit of my application. These did not work. The error is in the 'REMOTE BUILD OUTPUT' section

Comment: Well, after bashing my head against the wall all day, I figured out that .yaml file names that are not named 'app.yaml' are failing to deploy.  I have a few different yaml files in my root for different deployments. This has worked fine for the last few years. Maybe a bug on the backend, or are custom yaml files no longer supported?

Comment: According to [this](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/php/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml#intro), you should be able to give a unique name to your app.yaml file, as long as you use the same name when deploying with gcloud. Could you please confirm that?

Comment: @gbones I edited your question initially and replaced your statements on `yaml` with `app.yaml`, assuming you were using said nomenclature, which may have lead to some information about the issue to be lost and resulted in a more difficult troubleshooting path. I've completely overseen it, sorry about that - I changed it back so hopefully this will help future community members facing similar issues.

Comment: Ok, @Maxim. I did not really consider it at first either. Yes Artemis, that is what I have been using for the last 2 years at least. Perhaps it's a cloud deploy bug. I have reached out to Google Support also, I'll await their answer on it.

Answer (score 1):

It has been confirmed by the Google App Engine Team that this was an issue from their side, which prevented a custom-named yaml file from being deployed.

> The App Engine Team has advised that this issue was due to a change on
>   our side that prevented flex builds. That change was rolled back.